# How to measure pairwise distances between two sets of points?

Tags: python, geospatial, euclidean-distance

I have two datasets (csv files). Both of them contains latitudes-longitudes of two sets (220 and 4400) of points. Now I want to measure pairwise distances (miles) between these two sets of points (220 x 4400). How can I do that in python? Similar to this problem: https://gist.github.com/rochacbruno/2883505

[image: Example of one dataset]

Comment: Are you asking about the math, or what exactly was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: What are "stop ids"?

Comment: @mkrieger1, just consider them (stop ids) a set of points. I edited that part of the question. In simple words, I am looking for a python code to calculate distances between latitude longitude pairs.

Comment: Why don’t you write this code yourself, that would be faster. Why don’t you use the square root of the sum of the squared differences between two latitudes and two longitudes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best is to use `sklearn` which has exactly what you ask for.

Say we have some sample data

```
towns = pd.DataFrame({
    "name" : ["Merry Hill", "Spring Valley", "Nesconset"],
    "lat" : [36.01, 41.32, 40.84],
    "long" : [-76.7, -89.20, -73.15]
})

museum = pd.DataFrame({
    "name" : ["Motte Historical Car Museum, Menifee", "Crocker Art Museum, Sacramento", "World Chess Hall Of Fame, St.Louis", "National Atomic Testing Museum, Las", "National Air and Space Museum, Washington", "The Metropolitan Museum of Art", "Museum of the American Military Family & Learning Center"],
    "lat" : [33.743511, 38.576942, 38.644302, 36.114269, 38.887806, 40.778965, 35.083359],
    "long" : [-117.165161, -121.504997, -90.261154, -115.148315, -77.019844, -73.962311, -106.381531]
})
```

You can use `sklearn` distance metrics, which has the haversine implemented

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric

dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
```

After you extract the `numpy` array values with

```
places_gps = towns[["lat", "long"]].values
museum_gps = museum[["lat", "long"]].values
```

you simply

```
EARTH_RADIUS = 6371.009

haversine_distances = dist.pairwise(np.radians(places_gps), np.radians(museum_gps) )
haversine_distances *= EARTH_RADIUS
```

to get the distances in `KM`. If you need miles, multiply with constant.

If you are only interested in the closest few, or all within radius, check out `sklearn` [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) algorithm which also has the haversine implemented. It is much faster.

---

Edit: To convert the output to a dataframe use for instance

```
pd_distances = pd.DataFrame(haversine_distances, columns=museum.name, index=towns.name, )
pd_distances
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Instead of array output, could you please tell how can I get the output in dataframe format? Say, an output consisting of 3 columns in this case (towns, museum, distance).

Comment: The output is a distance-matrix. If you want to sort them by distance for each town and create a list that is possible, but won't be a nice dataframe as you get lists/arrays as data. So the 3 columns suggestion is a little hard for me to create. I made the more straightforward distance matrix.